# Oracle Complex Hierarchy

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchy

In general, I have a Key (Contract) that changes to another key in a row.
The changed Key can be changed and for that we have another row.
The key go back as it was at the beginning.
I need a row for the first Key (where it all started) and the newest Key (that is skipping all the other keys that were in between).

This creates the table:

```
CREATE TABLE CONTRACT ("NAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
                                   ,"OLD_CONTRACT" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
                                   ,"NEW_CONTRACT" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
                                   ,"NEW_CONTRACT_DATE" NUMBER(10)) ;

COMMIT;

INSERT INTO CONTRACT (NAME,OLD_CONTRACT,NEW_CONTRACT,NEW_CONTRACT_DATE)
VALUES ('John','1','10',20180101);
INSERT INTO CONTRACT (NAME,OLD_CONTRACT,NEW_CONTRACT,NEW_CONTRACT_DATE)
VALUES ('Ronnie','10','6',20180107);
INSERT INTO CONTRACT (NAME,OLD_CONTRACT,NEW_CONTRACT,NEW_CONTRACT_DATE) 
VALUES ('Kim','6','1',20180128);
INSERT INTO CONTRACT (NAME,OLD_CONTRACT,NEW_CONTRACT,NEW_CONTRACT_DATE) 
VALUES ('Nathaly','3','2',20180419);
INSERT INTO CONTRACT (NAME,OLD_CONTRACT,NEW_CONTRACT,NEW_CONTRACT_DATE)
VALUES ('Gorge','2','8',20180713);
INSERT INTO CONTRACT (NAME,OLD_CONTRACT,NEW_CONTRACT,NEW_CONTRACT_DATE) 
VALUES ('Allen','8','20',20180921);
INSERT INTO CONTRACT (NAME,OLD_CONTRACT,NEW_CONTRACT,NEW_CONTRACT_DATE) 
VALUES ('Tom','4','11',20170103);

COMMIT;
```

This is how it looks

```
Name    old_key      new Key    Updated date 
----    -------      -------    ------------ 
John      1             10      20180101
Ronnie    10             6      20180107
Kim        6             1      20180128
Nathaly    3             2      20180419
Gorge      2             8      20180713
Allen      8             20     20180921
Tom        4             11     20170103
```

First 3 rows returns only ONE ROW.

```
Old Key  New Key
-------  -------
   1        1
```

Why? Because

```
1   Becomes 10
10  Becomes 6
6   Becomes 1
```

Next 3 rows returns only ONE ROW.

```
Old Key  New Key
-------  -------
   3        20
```

Why? Because

```
3   Becomes 2
2   Becomes 8
8   Becomes 20
```

Last row returns ONE ROW.

```
Old Key  New Key
-------  -------
   4        11
```

Why? Because

```
4   Becomes 11
```

I need help writing Query for this scenario

Comment: Could you provide expected output? Only 2 columns `Old Key` and  `New Key`?

Comment: So what are the rules for deciding what value of `old_key` to start with? The first example `1 -> 1` seems particularly troubling.

Comment: "Could you provide expected output?" ....
Yes. 2 Columns- Old key & New Key
"So what are the rules for deciding what value..."
There are many keys , there is no main Key

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query using CONNECT BY that does the connection that you want and need.
From its results you have to select the first old_contract and the last new_contract.

```
SELECT NAME,OLD_CONTRACT,NEW_CONTRACT, LEVEL, rownum 
FROM contract
START WITH OLD_CONTRACT = 3
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR NEW_CONTRACT = OLD_CONTRACT
```

Results

```
NAME    OLD_CONTRACT    NEW_CONTRACT    LEVEL   ROWNUM
Nathaly 3               2               1       1
Gorge   2               8               2       2
Allen   8               20              3       3
```

Comment: Thank you!
It canno't have "START WITH" because the are many keys at the same level.
second , the key is varchar so there is no ordering.
third , you didn't mention how to identify the "group" to take the first row and the last.